# Merging different depending LiveData objects into one

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-livedata, mediatorlivedata

Here is my problem.
I have to generate data from three different `LiveData` objects into one object. Two of them depending of one of them. The observer should only be triggered if all three object data was received.

Here is an example:

The resulting object contains information of a product and a specific review rating of this product. The result object looks something like this:

```
public class RatedProduct {
    private String productKey; // database key to the product
    private String ratingKey; // database key to the specific rating
    private Product product; // the product information
    private Rating rating; // the specifiv rating information
    private HashMap<String, Boolean> customTags; // list of tags
...
}
```

The sources distributed over different databases locations.

The first object `UserRating` contains additional data (`customTags`) and only two keys, referencing to the product and to the rating information.

```
public class UserRating {
    private String ratingKey;
    private String productKey;
    private HashMap<String, Boolean> customTags;
...
}
```

The `Rating` and `Product` objects holding the specific information.

```
public class Rating {
    private float value; // value of the rating
    private String productKey; // database key to the product
    private String ratingComment;
...
}
```

```
public class Product {
    private String name; // name of the product
    private HashMap<String, Boolean> ratings; // list of all ratings
...
}
```

The task is to gather all the data from `UserRating`, `Rating` and `Product` into one `RatedProduct` but hiding the necessary steps.

I think the best way is to use three different `LiveData` objects and merging them with the help of a `MediatorLiveData`

But I'm not sure how to do this in the right manner. I'm a little bit stucked. I know how to add the `UserRatingLiveData` as source to the `MediatorLiveData` but I'm lost how to add the remaining two, call them `RatingLiveData` and `ProductLiveData` with respect to the keys contained in `UserRatingLiveData`.

The  second problem is, that `MediatorLiveData<RatedProduct>` should only update if all data was retrieved and not if only one of them.

That's what I have (more or less nothing). The interessting part is `LiveData<RatedProduct> getRatedProductLiveData()`  I guess:

```
public class UserViewModel extends ViewModel {
    ...
    private UserRatingsLiveData mUserRatingsLiveDate;

    public UserViewModel() {

        //
        // Getting current user
        FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if (mUser != null) {
            this.mUserRatingsLiveDate =
                    new UserRatingsLiveData(
                            mUsersDatabaseReference.child(mUser.getUid() + "/" + DB_PATH_RATINGS));
        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "mUser is NULL");
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    public LiveData<RatedProduct> getRatedProductLiveData() {
        final MediatorLiveData<RatedProduct>  liveDataMerger = new MediatorLiveData<> ();
        final UserRating receivedUserRating = new UserRating();


        liveDataMerger.addSource(this.mUserRatingsLiveDate, new Observer<UserRating>() {
            public void onChanged(UserRating userRatings) {

            }
        });
        return liveDataMerger;
    }
}
```

As an additional hint: The data base is a Firebase RealTimeDatabase, if this could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like that:

```
class MyViewModel {
    val mainLiveData: LiveData<CustomClass> get() = _mainLiveData

    private val firstLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val secondLiveData : MutableLiveData<Int>? = null
    private val thirdLiveData : MutableLiveData<Long>? = null

    private val _mainLiveData = MediatorLiveData<CustomClass>().also { mergeLiveData ->
        mergeLiveData.addSource(firstLiveData) {
           if (secondLiveData != null ) mergeLiveData.removeSource(secondLiveData)
           if (thirdLiveData != null) mergeLiveData.removeSource(thirdLiveData)

           secondLiveData = getSecondLiveData(firstLiveData.value)
           thirdLiveData = getThirdLiveData(firstLiveData.value)

           mergeLiveData.addSource(secondLiveData) {
               updateMainLiveData(mergeLiveData)
           }
           
           mergeLiveData.addSource(thirdLiveData) {
               updateMainLiveData(mergeLiveData)
           }
        }
    }

    private fun updateMainLiveData(mainLiveData: MediatorLiveData<CustomClass>) {
        val first = firstLiveData.value ?: return
        val second = secondLiveData.value ?: return
        val third = thirdLiveData.value ?: return

        mainLiveData.value = CustomClass(first, second, third)
    }

    data class CustomClass(
        val first: String,
        val second: Int,
        val third: Long
    )
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thank you. I will give them a try, but at first I need a crash course in Kotlin :D As I understand your approach, it will work only if you know all database sources of the three `LiveData` objects at the same time. In my case I nee at first `firstLiveData`, because it holds the keys of `secondLiveData` and `thirdLiveData`. After that I can add them as a source of `mergeLiveData`. Am I right?

Comment: What type is mergeLiveData or is this a Kotlin thing, that there is no definition of them?

Comment: In the block `also` we can give a name for that variable. `mergeLiveData` is `_mainLiveData = MediatorLiveData<CustomClass>()`, just for using in the `also` block I give a name like that.